# It is possible for cabal.project to have two seperate build units?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I want to avoid cabal dependency hell problem.

I have three packges.
`cabal.project`

```
packages: schema/
          client/
          server/
```

Where `client` would depend on `schema`, and `server` depend on `schema`.
Building `schema&client` or `schema&server` would be fine.
But `client` and `server` have transitive dependency on two versions of same package.

Is it possible to group build units in cabal.
So I can build `schema&client` and `schema&server` separately to avoid the dependency hell in cabal, under a single `cabal.project`.

Comment: The source structure you’re showing indicates that you’re in control of both `server` and `client`. Why would you even _want_ them to use different versions of the same package?

Comment: Sadly, that is by deeper transitive dependency that I have no control of:(  I modified the question to address this point now.

Comment: Probably the right thing is to vendor whatever libraries are causing them to have different dependency trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is impossible to use two conflicting packages in one cabal project.

As an alternative, you could consider making two project files, e.g. `client.project` and `server.project`, and switching between them using the [`--project-file` cabal option](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-project.html#cmdoption-0).